Combining the "WITH clause" and "MERGE statement" directly into one SELECT statement
Is it possible to get a result if I combine the WITH clause and MERGE statement directly into one SELECT statement? Combining WITH clause with INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE works but MERGE does not work with "WITH clause" in DB2.
Here are fiddle link for INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE.
and fiddle link for MERGE
DB2 version: DB2 v11.5.9.0
Platform: DB2 LUW

--- db2 code:

-- Create table target_table
CREATE TABLE target_table (id, name, value) AS 
(
    VALUES 
        (1, 'item1', 1),
        (2, 'item1', 1),
        (3, 'item1', 1),
        (4, 'item2', 1),
        (5, 'item3', 1),
        (6, 'item3', 1),
        (7, 'item3', 9),
        (8, 'item3', 9),
        (9, 'item3', 9)
) WITH DATA;

-- Create table source_table
CREATE TABLE source_table (id, name, value) AS 
(
    VALUES 
        (1, 'item1', 2),
        (10, 'item1', 10)
) WITH DATA;

-- Merge operation with a CTE for insert and update
WITH cte_1_insert AS (
    SELECT COUNT(1) AS dummy_1 
    FROM NEW TABLE (
        MERGE INTO target_table AS tgt
        USING source_table AS src
        ON tgt.id = src.id
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
            UPDATE SET tgt.name = src.name, tgt.value = src.value
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
            INSERT (id, name, value) VALUES (src.id, src.name, src.value)
    )
)

-- Select statement to retrieve from target_table
SELECT * FROM target_table ORDER BY id ASC;



expected result:

------------------------------------|
|ID     |NAME       |VALUE  |
|1      |item1      |2      |
|2      |item1      |1      |
|3      |item1      |1      |
|4      |item2      |1      |
|5      |item3      |1      |
|6      |item3      |1      |
|7      |item3      |9      |
|8      |item3      |9      |
|9      |item3      |9      |
------------------------------------|



It seems as if you're trying for a NEW/FINAL data-change-table-reference ... I don't think MERGE is supported.  But it will be dependent on your Platform and version of Db2.

@Charles I am having DB2 version: DB2 v11.5.9.0 and Platform: DBeaver

DBeaver isn't a platform..  Db2 Platforms are Linux/Unix/Windows (LUW), IBM i (midrange), IBM z (mainframe), or Db2 Cloud I suppose (I believe that's a modified LUW version).  11.5 could be LUW or Z.

Dn2, which is running on windows, and it has LUW platform.

the Db2-LUW docs suggest that the data-change-table-reference (aka NEW TABLE ) is applicable to searched-UPDATE, searched-DELETE, or INSERT statements (i.e. does not mention MERGE).
